# Does this logic lead to my conclusion?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

I have the following conditions on two related functions, $f,g:\Bbb Z^2\to \Bbb Z$ where $f$ has range $A$ and $g$ has range $B$:

> (i) Given $u\in\Bbb Z^+$, specify the interval $W_u=[u+1,2u].$ Then $|A\cap W_u|\geq|B\cap W_u|$
>
> (ii) $\exists a,b:f(a,b)=2x\iff\\ \exists c,d:g(c,d)=x$
>
> (iii) $\exists z\in \Bbb Z^+:\forall a,b\in\Bbb Z,f(a,b)\neq z$

From these, I want to say that we can choose $u$ such that $z\in W_u$, and therefore from (i) we know that there must be some value within the interval $W_u$ that $g$ cannot attain.  Now from contrapositive of (ii) we can say that there must be some value within the interval $W_{2u}$ that $f$ cannot attain.

I want to use the above as the basis for an induction to say that the cardinality of $\Bbb Z\setminus A$ and of $\Bbb Z\setminus B$ must be infinite.  Does this logic hold?

Comment: What does $W_u$ look like if the $z$ from (iii) is negative?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: ah, let me fix that.  $z$ should be non-negative.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are into $\Bbb Z$, then what does it even mean to say that they have codomain $Q$ and $R$?

Comment: And both your functions are defined to have codomain $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I see that I meant to say "range" instead of "codomain"...  I'll fix that.

Comment: I guess that I'm not entirely sure what you mean by $Q$ and $R$. Do you mean the rational and the real numbers?

Comment: No, they are just names.  Call them $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: yes, the choices of $Q,R$ were unfortunate in their similarities to $\Bbb Q,\Bbb R$.  I've adjusted the set designations.

Comment: This question has no sense.. you need to impose i, ii and iii for any function to be able to have this valid. The functions have not any need to meet those for free. What if $u<1$.

Comment: And which is the actual question?!

Comment: What does "given an interval" mean?

Comment: @DanielV I read it, "for each interval $W_u = ...$".

Comment: @hyprfrco:  the actual question is, is the logic following the conditions imposed on the specified functions correct, i.e., can an induction be built this way?  And yes, these conditions are imposed, or rather, I have found functions that match these conditions.

Comment: @DanielV: I tried to clarify the "given an interval" bit.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to define $W_u = [u,2u-1]$.  If $W_u = [u+1, 2u]$, then the first nonempty $W_u$ is $[2,2]$.  I'm using the revised definition below.

---

By (iii) $\mathbb{Z} \setminus A \neq \emptyset$; hence if $\mathbb{Z} \setminus A$ is finite, it has a maximum $m$.  Since (iii) guarantees the existence of a positive element of $\mathbb{Z} \setminus A$, it must be $m>0$.

If $m > 0$, $m \in W_m$.  Since

$$ m > |A \cap W_m| \geq |B \cap W_m| , $$

there exists $n \in W_m \setminus B$ such that $\forall c,d : g(c,d) \neq n$ and $\forall a,b : f(a,b) \neq 2n$.  Therefore $2n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus A$, but $2n > n \geq m$ contradicting the assumption that $m$ is maximum.

---

Note that $\mathbb{Z} \setminus B \neq \emptyset$ because of $\mathbb{Z} \setminus A \neq \emptyset$ and (i).  Hence if $\mathbb{Z} \setminus B$ is finite, it has maximum $p$.  Since $\mathbb{Z} \setminus A$ has no maximal element, there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus A$ such that $q > p$ and $q > 1$.  But

$$ |A \cap W_q| < q = |B \cap W_q|, $$

which contradicts (i).

Comment: Uh, in your definition of $W_u, W_1=[1,1]$.  In my definition of $W_u, W_1=[2,2]$.  I'm not sure I see the point of changing this definition.  Otherwise, yes, this matches with what I thought should happen.

Comment: If specific functions are found ($f,g$) that make using one version of the interval better than the other, of course I would use the definition that works the best.

Comment: @abiessu I want to be able to claim that $m \in W_u$ for some $u$ so that I can make use of (i). Should the $z$ guaranteed by (iii) be $1$, and $W_u = [u+1,2u]$, that would not work because I'd only have $m \geq 1$ and $1$ is in no $W_u$.

Comment: There may be other acceptable (or even preferable) ways to fix the argument, but changing the definition of $W_u$ seems reasonably straightforward.